# How to determine size of array in Matlab/Octave `mexFunction` (not nrhs)

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave, mex

I want to give an array of arbitrary size to my `mexFunction` but somehow can't determine the size of it in my C-code. I have already tried `sizeof(prhs[0])` (assuming that the array is the first input argument) but this always returns 8 - regardless of the array size and the type. So, any ideas? I'm using Octave by the way.

Comment: I guess you are just starting with the mex interface and C (considering that you thought that `sizeof` would have given you the answer). Since you are using Octave, try an [oct file](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Oct_002dFiles.html#Oct_002dFiles) instead. Octave's C++ API will be simpler and more similar to the Octave language itself.

Comment: But to answer your question anyway (and I will stress again that if you are using Octave, you'll be better off with an oct file instead), use the functions `mxGetNumberOfDimensions` and `mxGetDimensions`. The Octave manual section on [Working with Matrices and Arrays in Mex-files](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Working-with-Matrices-and-Arrays-in-Mex_002dFiles.html) and [Octave's doxygen reference for mex interface](http://octave.org/doxygen/4.0/df/d4e/mex_8cc.html)

Comment: Thnx for the reply, while the solution presented here is probably the correct one, Octave crashes whenever I use the functions in my C-code. I will take a look at the oct files.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned on the comments that you are trying to use oct files, here's how to do it (you should still go through the manual section on [oct-files](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Oct_002dFiles.html)):

```
$ cat foo.cc 
#include <octave/oct.h>

DEFUN_DLD (foo, args, ,
           "foo help text")
{
  if (args.length () != 1)
    {
      print_usage ();
      return octave_value_list ();
    }

  const NDArray m = args(0).array_value ();
  if (error_state)
    {
      error ("foo: first input must be a numeric N dimensional array");
      return octave_value_list ();
    }

  const dim_vector dims = m.dims ();
  for (int i = 0; i < dims.length (); i++)
    octave_stdout << "Dim " << i << " has length " << dims(i) << std::endl;

  return octave_value_list ();
}
$ mkoctfile foo.cc 
$ octave
octave:1> foo (rand (5, 3, 1, 2))
Dim 0 has length 5
Dim 1 has length 3
Dim 2 has length 1
Dim 3 has length 2
octave:2> foo ("bar")
error: invalid conversion from string to real N-d array
error: foo: first input must be a numeric N dimensional array
```

If you really want to use the mex interface, here's a simplified version with no check whatsoever (it will segfault if you give the wrong input):

```
$ cat foo.c
#include "mex.h"

void
mexFunction (int nlhs, mxArray* plhs[],
             int nrhs, const mxArray* prhs[])
{

  const mwSize nd = mxGetNumberOfDimensions (prhs[0]);
  const mwSize* dims = mxGetDimensions (prhs[0]);

  for (int i = 0; i < nd; i++)
    mexPrintf("Dim %i has length %i\n", i, dims[i]);

  return;
}
$ mkoctfile --mex foo.c
$ octave
octave:1> foo (rand (5, 2, 3))
Dim 0 has length 5
Dim 1 has length 2
Dim 2 has length 3
```